# How to restart python script inside bash script every x hours?

Tags: python, linux, bash, restart

I have a quite simple question about starting and restarting python scripts inside an bash script. I hope it's not an duplicate but I didn't find a similiar question. 
 I'm using a bash script which starts a couple of python scripts every time I create a docker container, but It should be probabaly the same on all linux based machines. It's simple as:
 
 `python3 /mnt/device/script.py &`
 
 Now the script will keep running and measure the brightness until the container is stopped. Now I figured out that there are some problems with the sensor library which are brightly discussed on github and still not solved which causes the script to stop every couple of hours. For me It would be enough to have just some command which restarts my script which is running in the background every x hours to avoid that error.
 So what I'm looking for ist some command which will be like the follwing:
 
 `python3 for hour=1 /mnt/device/script.py restart &`

 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Bash `timeout` command to send a signal to kill the Python script.

```sh
restart=""
while true; do
    timeout 3600 python3 /mnt/device/script.py $restart
    restart="restart"
done &
```

I'm guessing you don't *really* need this to run in the background (so maybe take out the `&`) and that you literally want `restart` to be passed as an argument after the first time.

Comment: There is no indication that OP needs the `$restart` argument. Without it, it might be also possible to make it one liner, like `watch timeout 1h python3 /mnt/device/script.py &`

Comment: The second example in the OP's question includes a `restart` argument. I am assuming they mean that literally. The variable is empty when the loop runs the first time, so `$restart` gets expanded to nothing; then on subsequent iterations, it gets expanded to the literal string `restart`. Obviously if this is not actually desired, take it out, or perhaps the OP could clarify what exactly they need.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I'm not sure about the timeout in the first comment. So I just need a command which starts the script again. Is that what timeout does or is it looking for the script to stop and then starting the script again?

Comment: `timeout` simply stops it after a given period of time. The `while true` loop takes care of running a new instance immediately after the previous one finishes. The `watch` command is nonstandard, but there is one which could replace the `while true` loop. (Actually `timeout` is not standard either, but it's pretty ubiquitous, as it's part of the GNU core utilities.)

Comment: @tripleee Correct, OP seems to require such an argument (I don't know why, but yes, it is required anyway). My bad. Note that `watch` will cause 2 seconds delay (by default) on each loop of the script.